# Nodejs connecting to Couchbase database

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I am trying to connect to Couchbase database and I am using the sample NodeJS SDK code from Couchbase website but I am getting error. Following is my code:

```
var couchbase = require('couchbase')

async function main() {
  const clusterConnStr = "cb.zbextwxyrtpxpht.cloud.couchbase.com"
  const username = 'couchbase-admin'
  const password = 'Password1234$$'
  const bucketName = 'travel-sample'

  console.log("Connecting to couchbase");

  const cluster = await couchbase.connect(clusterConnStr, {
    username: username,
    password: password,
    timeouts: {
      kvTimeout: 10000, // milliseconds
    },
  })
}

// Run the main function
main()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('ERR:', err)
    process.exit(1)
  })
  .then(process.exit)
```

I am getting the following error:
ERR: [Error: unambiguous_timeout] { code: 14 }

Please help me.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this solves it, but I think your connection string needs to be couchbases://cb.**********.cloud.couchbase.com

Comment: https://blog.couchbase.com/quickstart-connect-to-couchbase-capella-using-node-js/
flow this URL step by step work with that code i get database connect successfully...